# How can I enable xmonad window manager with xrdp? (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ubuntu, xmonad, xrdp

On ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME desktop. I installed xmonad as a window manager.  When I connect to my pc with xrdp, the xmonad does not "load" only the gnome. How can I use xmonad with xrdp?